# Which is related package of pgf-umlcd for creating uml use case diagram?

Tags: diagrams

I know `pgf-umlcd` package and I use this for making uml class diagram. I also know the `pgf-umlsd` package. Now, I need a package for making uml use case diagram for my lab project report. But, I can't choose which package is best for me.

Please give me the package name that is similar to `pgf-umlcd` or easy to learning when having knowledge of previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "related" package in the sense that the author of `pgf-umlcd` and `pgf-umlsd` hasn't made a package for use case diagrams. At least not any that is published [on GitHub](https://github.com/xuyuan?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=pgf&type=&language=).

The `tikz-uml` package on the other hand, which can be downloaded from http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/, does have features built in for use case diagrams. See chapter 3 in the manual (also available on that website). The easiest way of using it is to place `tikz-uml.sty` in the same folder as your `.tex` file, there are some instructions for making `.sty` files generally available in [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)